# Droid Explorer Setup problem : cannot start service exception

Tags: droid-explorer

When I try to add the SDK path I always end up with an error message. I have checked that the path is correct, added the platforms required, etc. 
This is the message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service DroidExplorerService on computer '.'. ---> 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
at DroidExplorer.Bootstrapper.Panels.StartServicePanel.StartService()
```

Does any one have any ideas?

Comment: What is the path you gave for the sdk?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of Droid Explorer.*

This message is typically not about the SDK. This usually happens when you try to update your version of Droid Explorer. It happens because Droid Explorer first removes the Service and then creates the new service. Sometimes, Windows does not completely let go of the original service and the installer is unable to start the new service.

Usually a reboot will allow the new service to start successfully. If you got that far, you don't even need to reinstall after reboot, just a reboot will suffice.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it without a reboot?

Comment: @bgmCoder no, because windows will not allow you to create the new service until it can safely clean up the old one. And when it gets in this state, really a reboot of the PC is the only option.

Comment: I mean, how can I do it manually?  kill/stop the service and then run the installer again?

Comment: The only way to fix it is to reboot. windows will not release the service and allow it to be installed until it is released.

Comment: And if a reboot does not fix it?